# Move all zeroes to the end of a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, swap, zero

Basically the code is asking me to move all zeroes towards the end of the list. Here is my code so far:

```
def moveZerosToEnd(l):
  for i in l:
    #look for zeros
    if int(i) == 0:
      j = nz(l,i)
      #swap zero with nonzero
      l[i], l[j] =  l[j], l[i]
  return l
    
def nz(l,i):
  #look for nonzero
  while i < len(l) and l[i] == 0:
    #progress if zero
    i += 1
  #return nonzero value
  return i
            


l = []
for i in range(5): l.append(int(input()))
moveZerosToEnd(l)
print(l)
```

However, whenever I type in five numbers, it just results in the same list unaltered. I am wondering what I did wrong here and how to fix it.

Comment: The function returns the result of its work. You need to assign the result of your function to a new name, and have a look at that variable.

Comment: @kwinkunks No they don't need to do that. The function alters the same list passed in and returns it as well. There is only one list in the program.

Comment: I think `nz(l,i)` is expecting `i` to be an index in the list; but when you call it from `moveZerosToEnd` you are actually passing a *value* from the list.

Comment: `sorted(my_list,key=lambda x:x==0)`  I think would do this

Comment: The PROBLEM here is that `i` is an element of the list, not the INDEX of an element in the list, which is what your swap expects.  You would need to use `enumerate` to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this homemade example.

retrieve all the elements in your list that are not "0" and create a new list out of this

extend every occurance of "0" into this new list

```
your_list = [5,4,3,2,1,0,0,0,-1,-2]
new_list = [i for i in your_list if i != 0]
new_list.extend([0]*your_list.count(0))
```

output

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `[[0]*your_list.count(0)][0]` can just be `[0]*your_list.count(0)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's very true. It was kind of weird having to index the list at the end. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use remove() and append()

```
def moveZerosToEnd(l):
    for i in l:
    #look for zeros
        if(i == 0):
            l.remove(i)
            l.append(i)
    return l

l = []
for i in range(5): l.append(int(input("What is the number: ")))
moveZerosToEnd(l)
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother all hassle?  The simplest approach for this *move_zeros* to the end is one-liner to use the tricks of *True* or *False* in the sorted key *(lambda):*

It's to return the same list (in-place sort),  but if you need a new list, you can do so easily.

```
A = [5,4, 0,3, 0, 2,1,0,-1,-2]
A.sort(key=lambda x: x == 0 )    # trick:  test item if is zero, "True"
                                 # all non-zero num. are "False" 
                                 # all False comes before Truth

# Or this:
A[:] = sorted(A, key=lambda x: x == 0)
```

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0]
```